Unknown Player's Mate in Eight
This chess problem has a special rule: a white pawn can only promote to a white rook, which lands on the board wearing a helmet and vest that protect it from being captured on the first turn after it spawns in. Solve for checkmate and use White's eight moves to determine the unknown player's identity.

FEN:

b1k2b1r/P5pn/PP3p2/bB2P2P/1NN3RN/q1RpN1pB/1q1q1nK1/5r2 w - - 0 1


If a white pawn can only promote to a white rook, then how did white get 4 knights and 2 light-coloured bishops? Also, before Nf2, White moved into check. (Sorry I just realised there's no retrograde-analysis tag)

@BenjaminWang Let's say the unknown player just took control and the special rule only applies starting now. Also, Nf2 was actually a capture.

Not really relevant to the puzzle but was the last move Nf2 also a capture? If not then it's impossible for white because the position you show has white in check(both before and after Nf2), but white cannot move to put itself in check. Either Nf2 was also a capture or white just did an illegal move

@dvx2718 Yes, we can deduce that Nf2 was in fact a capture.

We cannot draw any conclusions. Because the position is obviously illegal.

@ЭлсиРинген How so?

@noedne I reckon that ЭлсиРинген refers to the fact that black currently has 15 units but the white pawns had to capture twice, so the position cannot be reachable by legal moves. (But since this is not a retrograde analysis puzzle, this is probably not relevant here.)

Ah, fair point, but at least that shouldn't interfere with solving the puzzle.

Let's start with the obvious

 1. b7+. 1….. Bxb7+ is the only viable option for black (1….. Kd8 2. bxa8=R+ Ke7 3. Re8+ Kf7 4. Nd6+ Kg8 5. Bc4# or 4….. Bxd6 5. e6#, or 1….. Kc7 2. Ned5+ Kd8 3. bxa8=R#.)


The obvious 2. axb7+ seems to be no good here; 2….. Kxb7 and we’re already running out of checks. So instead let’s try our other check- 2. Re4+. Black now has five legal moves in the position:
2….. Kd8 swiftly loses to 3. a8=R+ Bc8 (helmet) 4. Rxc8+ Ke7 5. Re8+ Kf7 6. Be6#.
2….. Kc7 leads to 3. Nbd5+ Kd8 4. a8=R+ Bc8 5. Rxc8#.
2….. f5 results in 3. Nd6+ Kd8 (double check!) 3. a8=R+ Bc8 4. Raxc8+ Ke7 5. Re8#.


That leaves 2….. Ng4+ and 2….. Nxh3+. They’re basically the same line; either essentially forces 3. Nxd2+. Black has three ways to get out of the check:
Taking the rook is no good; either Qaxc3 or Qcxc3 leads to 4. a8=R+ Kc7 5. Nbd5+ Bxd5 6. Nxd5#.
Blocking the check doesn’t work either. Bc7 leads to a8=R#, and Bc5 leads to 4. a8=R+ Kc7 5. Nbd5+ Bxd5 6. Nxd5# again.


That leaves 3….. Kd8. 4. a8=R+ is the clear response, since the rook cannot be taken. Bc8 leads to 5. Raxc8+ Ke7 6. Re8#. So that leaves 4….. Ke7. From here, there are no more gimmicks; it’s a simple mate in 4: 5. Ng6+ Ke6 (5….. Kf7 6. Bc4+ Bd5 7. Bxd5#) 6. Re8+ Kf7 7. e6+ Kg8 8. Ne7#.
To summarize, the full list of moves is 1. b7+ Bxb7+ 2. Re4+ Nxh3+ 3. Nxd2+ Kd8 4. a8=R+ Ke7 5. Ng6+ Ke6 6. Re8+ Kf7 7. e6+ Kg8 8. Ne7#.

As for the mystery player’s identity,

if you put all the letters (ignoring x for capture) from white’s moves together, you get video game developer Brendan Greene.


I've added spoiler blocks to your answer, for the benefit of future solvers. Feel free to look at your answer in the Editor to see how to do this.

Nice analysis of variations! I think there's a small mistake in the 4...Bc8 alternative to the mainline because Black still has Kf7 after 6. Re8#.
